# AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython2macOsArmFramework'

Tags: python, macos, pip, modulenotfounderror

I was trying to configure pre-commit hooks and while running `pre-commit run --all-files` I got this error:

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/Users/dark_matter88/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8', '-mvirtualenv', '/Users/dark_matter88/.cache/pre-commit/repojfgkwtv7/py_env-python3.8')
return code: 1
stdout:
    AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython2macOsArmFramework'
```

I've tried to upgrade pip to resolve this issue `pip install --upgrade pip` and I received another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "/Users/admin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.packaging.requirements import Requirement
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging'
```

I tried to check versions of both pip and pip3, and now I'm also getting the same `No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging'` error. I've tried all the solutions I could find, but nothing's helped.
I'm thinking if it's related to having several versions of python installed.

Comment: same error here. This is related to virtualenv. If I just execute `virtualenv` in bash I get the same error message.

Answer (score 7):

For me on Debian after a OS upgrade, the global `python3-virtualenv` package had been installed, which was causing the same issue:

```
$ pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /tmp/test/Pipfile
Using default python from /usr/bin/python3 (3.9.2) to create virtualenv...
⠹ Creating virtual environment...AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython2macOsFramework'

✘ Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
```

After a `sudo apt remove python3-virtualenv` and `python3 -m pip install -U virtualenv pipenv` error was gone for me.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same error on Python 3.9.2 and virtualenv==20.23.0.

```
▶ virtualenv   
AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython2macOsFramework'
▶ virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.23.0 from ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
```

For some reason, after I uninstalled virtualenv with `pip uninstall virtualenv -y`, the server also had v20.4.0 still installed and this version worked without the error. I assume the v20.4.0 is a global package for all users of our server, the v20.23.0 was probably installed with the `--user` flag.

```
▶ virtualenv --version    
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
virtualenv 20.4.0+ds from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
▶ virtualenv              
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--read-only-app-data] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--reset-app-data] [--upgrade-embed-wheels] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--try-first-with py_exe]
                  [--creator {builtin,cpython3-posix,venv}] [--seeder {app-data,pip}] [--no-seed] [--activators comma_sep_list] [--clear] [--no-vcs-ignore] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--no-download | --download]
                  [--extra-search-dir d [d ...]] [--pip version] [--setuptools version] [--wheel version] [--no-pip] [--no-setuptools] [--no-wheel] [--no-periodic-update] [--symlink-app-data] [--prompt prompt] [-h]
                  dest
virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest
SystemExit: 2
▶ git commit -v
[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to /home/user/<user>/.cache/pre-commit/patch1684867373-780959.
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
```

Answer (score 1):

The same issue recently appeared on a BitBucket pipeline (while having no issue locally on a WSL pre-commit run).

The problem was solved by downgrading virtualenv from `20.23.0` to `20.19.0`